# JavaScript number validation

Tags: javascript, validation, int

I have trying to validate a number in JS. I have a while loop that checks the number is in a range and that it is a number. The loop works checking that it is in range but doesn't working checking that the number is valid (I.e isn't NaN). I have tried with both int and float but neither work.

Code:

```
while (isNaN(midday) == 'true' || midday >= 50){
        //validate that the number is w/n an expected range (0-50)
        alert("You entered an out out range or incorrect number")
        var midday = prompt("Enter number: " + pn);
        midday = parseFloat(midday);
    };
```

Thanks for any help: sorry if this seems simple!

Comment: Value `true` not equals string with value `true`.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked... Make 'true' into true; not a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

true is a symbol, not a string. You have 'true' instead of true. Try this.

```
var midday = 'asdf';
if (isNaN(midday) || 
midday >= 50) {
alert('isNan == true or >= 50');
}
else {
alert('none is true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN` method returns boolean value true/false. And you're comparing it with string value `true`. String value `true` not equals to boolean `true`. You can either use

```
if (isNaN(midday) == true || ...)
```

or simpler:

```
if (isNaN(midday) || ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

isNan return a boolean. You don't need to check if it's true.

```
var midday = prompt("Enter number: ");
if (isNaN(midday)){
        alert("Not a number")
}
else { alert('Your number is ' + midday); }
```

You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/
( I changed a while for an if because i don't like the while loop, you can change for you own purpose of course :) )

Comment: Hi, thanks. I kind of need it to work in the way I have set it up but thanks anyway; good answer!